# VSPackage load order - load before another VSPackage?

Tags: visual-studio, vspackage

How do you create a VSPackage that has a dependency on functionality in another VSPackage? In other words, if I have VSPackage A that exports a certain feature that I need in VSPackage B, how do I ensure that VSPackage B is loaded first?

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably, this is a [VS Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166389.aspx) that you're exposing from VSPackage B? If that's the case, Visual Studio will automatically load the package when you request it from VSPackage A via a call to [Package.GetService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.package.getservice.aspx).

There is also an [API method to force-load a package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsshell.loadpackage.aspx), but using it generally means you're doing something wrong. :-)    You should rely on VS to delay-load packages as necessary.